# How to create a GUI based window in Blender Game Engine that displays text?

Tags: game-engine

How to create a GUI based window in Blender Game Engine that displays text? So I was going to create a NPC chatting menu in my RPG based game, using only logic bricks. I found this to be difficuly because what I wanted to have happen is when the player is talking to the NPC, a window within the game pops-up and Displays what the NPC is saying.

Comment: Have you tried some Tutorials like for a [HUD](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QboViMztemI&index=11&list=PLda3VoSoc_TSS7ht07sCt8zDCyAenOG6i) or a [Health Bar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yg906oHzLRU&list=PLda3VoSoc_TSS7ht07sCt8zDCyAenOG6i&index=14)? Or maybe some [Word Wrapping](http://www.cgmasters.net/free-tutorials/fps-mouselook-script-plus-real-text/#chapter8) of a text overlay...

Comment: @Samoth the tutorials are familiar to me, I'll attempt at seeing what these will do, but to be honest, this would have been a good answer.

Comment: You know, in earlier days I just would have posted this as an answer - but there are crazy people here who are scared of links. They don't like the concept of Hyperlinks (which is a basic part of HTML...) to other sites which may eventually expire some day... But I'll give it another try.

Comment: @Samoth Pardon me, but this is SE site-wide policy. There is a special delete reason for it because it happens so often. This is a very important part of the way SE works. I would question whether it is an answer or not if it relies solely on external links. I am glad to see that you are considering revising this answer, and hope you eventually learn the quirks of this community and become a valuable member :)

Comment: @NᴏᴠɪᴄᴇIɴDɪsɢᴜɪsᴇ If you ask me Samoth is already quite a valuable contributor to this site ;) Especially considering how recently they joined.

Comment: @Samoth NᴏᴠɪᴄᴇIɴDɪsɢᴜɪsᴇ has a good point, this philosophy doesn't originate here. There has been [plenty](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/238438) of [debate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/238438) and [discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92505/238438) on this subject on the main meta, in case you are interested in reading more about the rational behind this.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can try to follow some Tutorials like for a [HUD](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QboViMztemI&index=11&list=PLda3VoSoc_TSS7ht07sCt8zDCyAenOG6i), a [Health Bar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yg906oHzLRU&list=PLda3VoSoc_TSS7ht07sCt8zDCyAenOG6i&index=14) or maybe some [Word Wrapping](http://www.cgmasters.net/free-tutorials/fps-mouselook-script-plus-real-text/#chapter8) of a text overlay...

Comment: Don't delete this answer - the question asker is happy with this kind of post... Yeah, links are sometimes very helpful.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with including links in answers (quite the contrary!), however *relying on them as the only piece of information* is discouraged for reasons you already seem to be aware of (linked content changing or disappearing). The solution is to to provide (at minimum) a brief quote or summary of the content at the other end of the link, so in the far future there is at least something to prevent the answer from becoming wholly useless.

Comment: @Samoth Well, to be honest, I already seen these tuts quiet some years ago. I forgot about them and they are very helpful back then and they are still helpful now, so really, that's all I need for now ;) - Thanks!

Comment: Actually these "answers" should preferably be comments, as someone who curates a playlist of videos I find from time to time videos get removed or made private which is very annoying. If say by chance the creators remove these videos in the future even say 2 years from now this now accepted answer is effectively useless. It's a gray area I agree but if you can't condense it or link to a written article at least *(that can be cached)* I'd recommend in the future leaving comments instead, we are trying to create an **archive** of answers, linking to external content defeats that purpose.

Comment: That being said, this post is "rare" or somewhat localized enough for an exception so it can stay up until its flagged (if and when) in the future for missing content or similar. :)

Comment: Well, I'll see if I can summarize some things. But there's a problem with the comments: You can't get reputation for them. So basically if someone wants to "thank" for a helpful link in a comment, there is no real possibility. Comments shouldn't be "Thanks" anyways. I'd vote for at least getting one point reputation for an upvoted comment then ;-)

Comment: @Samoth well if you can come up with a better answer that also b very well appreciated. I'm still working on the GUI Text thing.

Comment: Case in point: 1/3 of the links are now broken...